# Is it possible to make code blocks like those in markdown for html?

Tags: html, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Markdown support code blocks that are very useful. By specifying which language we want (like this  **```cpp**), we can have color syntax highlighting automatically too. Example shown below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    printf("hello");
}
```

So, my question is how do I do this on an html file?

I already know you can make code blocks, with this -> `<pre><code> write here </code></pre>`, but I want the syntax highlighting function.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to format code in a Stack Overflow question, or something else?

Comment: HTML code _is_ highlighted if you don't use inline code markers. Use the code button in the editor toolbar and create a full block.

Comment: @isherwood yeah, I see why you were confused. sorry. I'm trying to write a blog post in html and I would really like to have that code block function that's in markdown. Did that clear my question?

Comment: You'd load or write a JavaScript library to do it. You'll need to revise to ask a more specific question, though. This is still quite vague. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a library like [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Otherwise you would have to wrap every key word, variable, function name, operators, etc. in their own span tag and apply classes, creating a color schema for every distinct thing in every supported language.
Other than using a library (or creating your own, for fun) this is rather tedious.

*FYI*: Ever thought about right-click and inspect element of your example? Your example results in this HTML:

```html
<pre class="lang-cpp s-code-block hljs"><code><span class="hljs-meta">#<span class="hljs-meta-keyword">include</span> <span class="hljs-meta-string">&lt;iostream&gt;</span></span>
<span class="hljs-function"><span class="hljs-keyword">int</span> <span class="hljs-title">main</span><span class="hljs-params">()</span></span>{
    <span class="hljs-built_in">printf</span>(<span class="hljs-string">"hello"</span>);
}
</code></pre>
```

As you can see this would be pretty tedious to create yourself, so use a library for that.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know they had libraries for that. That's exactly what I was looking for :)